# What should we do if not getting an appropriate answer?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, specific-question, asking-questions

I have a question which I've been trying to solve a very long time. I posted it on Stack Overflow, and I got many answer after starting a bounty, but still my issue is unresolved although I have tried all logics metion in question including my effort. What should I do now?

[Android Spinner in two different activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38929897/how-to-change-the-position-of-a-spinner-according-to-position-of-other-spinner-i)

Answer (score 13):

The most important thing you can do on that question is to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You code looks complete, and is probably also verifiable in the sense that it actually shows the problem, but it sure doesn't look *minimal*!

I don't know a whole lot about Android, but I have a feeling this code can be significantly reduced, perhaps down to even a few lines.

Reducing the code means that it's easier to understand the problem since there is less distraction, plus many people simple can't be bothered to read long strips of code, so they're more likely to move on to the next question.

---

A second thing you can do is try to improve the writing of the text. I know it's not easy for non-native speakers, but there are some obvious mistakes that are distracting: no space after punctuation, space before punctuation, obvious spelling errors that my spell check catches, etc.

No one is expecting you to make it perfect, but every bit helps, and that paragraph *is* the first impression you give people. If that looks very sloppy (as it does now), then people are more likely to move on to the next question.

---

All of that being said, I'm afraid that Stack Overflow offers no guarantee of getting a correct answer... So while the above may help, it may not help *enough*... :-(

Comment: SO true... Just by enhancing the quality of the question (i.e. adhering to the guidelines in the help section) makes the possibility of getting an adequate answer significantly... Putting effort in the question comes back as putting effort into the answers - and also a wall of code will not get the attention of the real experts of the given field... If an asker scares away the people who could answer the question no wonder it will sink...

Comment: Answering questions in comments is also quite important.

Comment: The biggest problem with the question is that *it doesn't really ask a question*. It's just a dump of code, with a brief allusion to a problem.

Comment: Well answered!  These were almost exactly my thoughts after reading the OP's question.  One additional point with regard to the code: consistent formatting is pretty important.  People are not compilers: code formatting is *important* to help convey meaning and make code approachable by others.

Comment: The question was edited after I made this answer @CodyGray, it *was* a question with a specific problem description before... I am confused why the OP edited it to this...